# Is there an elegant way to parameterize Bootstrap modals in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-modal

I'm currently setting up a view in Laravel which contains a DataTable for orders with each row containing an order's data and among others a button for updating its status. Calling this action pops up a modal window with the necessary form parameters. That's where I figured that I had to update the one-time included modal according to the data of the selected row. Doing so is quite easy by adding a Javascript event listener for the button calling the modal, reading out the data from the affected row and inserting it into the modal.

```
$(document).on("click", "a.order_status_update", function () {
    var order_id = $(this).data('id');
    var data = table.row('#dt-id-' + order_id).data();
    // manipulating modal data...
});
```

But apart from it looking like a rather unclean solution to me, I'd also have to update the form action route, which contains the ID for the order to be updated, but would already be compiled by the Blade engine at that point.

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('orders.status.update', ['order_id' => /*not a fixed value!*/])}}">
```

Does someone know an ideal solution to this? Would it be better to generate the route myself in Javascript, or go for a fixed route instead and transmit the ID with the POST data? Are there even better solutions for parameterizing modals at all?

IIRC there would be a way to generate a fitting modal via AJAX request through a controller, though I'm not sure hope how this would be supposed to work.

Comment: I have encountered similar situation for my Laravel application. What I have tried is, to in the click handler, do an ajax call to the backend to update the record and if successful, do a refresh of datatables. In some cases, I had few fields to be send over, I have bundled them into FormData otherwise just a parameter to the ajax post request. You could declare the parameter as optional in the web.xml and then generate the path partially with laravel something like var Url = {{'route(order_update)'}} + '/' + id;

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this:

```
                @foreach($datas as $data)
                    <tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editData{{$data->id}}">
                        <td>{{$data->location}}</td>
                        <td>{{$data->address}}</td>
                        <td>{{$data->city}}</td>
                        <td>{{$data->time}}</td>
                        <td>{{$data->date}}</td>
                    </tr>

                  <div class="modal" id="editData{{$data->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                 //put all your data in here with $data 
                  </div>
               @endforeach
```

Basically with each go through the foreach loop you are creating a modal with that specific $data in it accessed by the unique id.

Comment: Seems like a legit solution, although this would simple multiply the modal itself. Since I'm working with Laravel DataTables (which pulls data via AJAX) I'd have to render the modal server-side with the data, and I'm suspecting this could drag performance if I had to pull an additional chunk of HTML for each row... but let me see how it works out for now.